# Trying to change connection host name in perl script that connect to SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, perl, dbi

We have a perl script on a Linux machine that connects to the SQL Server database and fetches information, we are trying to update the database host details but could not find parameter or variable that that does this in that script.

```
use strict;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;
use DBI qw(:sql_types);
use MIME::lite;
my $SQL_Datasource= 'dbi:ODBC:eventMSSQL';
my $SQL_user= 'user1';
my $SQL_password ='abc@123';
$dbh=DBI->connect($SQL_Datasourse,$SQL_user,$SQL_password)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script is connecting to a database defined under the **d**ata **s**ource **n**ame (DSN) `eventMSSQL`.

To change the *host* you connect to, you have three options.

First, you could modify this DSN definition to point to a different host.  This `eventMSSQL` DSN is defined somewhere in your Linux system's ODBC installation, probably in `/etc/odbc.ini` or `~/.odbc.ini`.

Alternatively, you could create a new DSN definition with a different host, and connect to that instead.

Finally, you could also change your `DBI->connect` *data_source* to include an ODBC connection string instead of a DSN, which would look something like `dbi:ODBC:Driver=...;Host=...;Port=...`.  (The DSN is a shorthand for that Driver/Host/Port/etc. specification.)

The DBD::ODBC::FAQ has an [entry on DSNs and connection strings](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBD-ODBC/FAQ#DSN-(Data-Source-Name)) which is illuminating here.

Answer (score 1):

Some ODBC drivers store the connection information in some dedicated files .

as a example UnixODBC store in a file named `odbcinst.ini` in **/etc**

source (  https://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/dbd_odbc_tutorial_part_1.html )

Comment: Hi Mike, in the osbcinst.ini I did see a Sql Server configuration, However I could not find parameter that holds host details.

Comment: I believe `odbcinst.ini` defines available ODBC _drivers_, not databases.  It answers the question, where can the ODBC installation find Firebird or PostgreSQL or SQL Server or Oracle or etc. drivers?  DSNs are specified elsewhere, referencing those driver definitions.